# Search has encountered a problem that prevents results from being returned after Microsoft Windows (KB5001078) update

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, sharepoint-search, people-search

This Tuesday (30.03.2021) we have installed the Security Update for Microsoft Windows (KB5001078) on the SharePoint 2016 server, after that the SharePoint search has stopped working, getting this error "**Search has encountered a problem that prevents results from being returned. If the issue persists, please contact your administrator.**"

[image: Sorry something went wrong]

Anyone experiencing the same issues? and what is the fix for this?

**Updated**:

Another update was installed - **Security Update for Microsoft Windows (KB4598243)**

**ULS Log**:

```
 Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.FlowHandleRegistry : Exceptions occurred when evaluating the flow.  Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.DataModel.EvaluationException: Evaluation failed in operator IndexLookupExecutor of type IndexLookupExecutor ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: ExpandSegments 
at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name) 
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SchemaDatabase.CreateManagedPropertyFromRow(Schema schema, IDataRecord record) 
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SchemaDatabase.PrivateGetManagedProperties(Schema schema) 
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SchemaDatabase.WrapFunction[T](String functionName, Func`1 wrappedFunction) 
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.ManagedPropertyCollection.Populate() 
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.ManagedPropertyCollection..ctor(Schema schemaToUse) 
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Schema.EnsureManagedPropertiesIsInitialized() 
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.QueryPipelineComponent.GetAAMEnabledProperties(Guid SearchServiceApplicationId) 
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.IndexLookupExecutor.ProcessFieldIteratorPatternForAlternateAccessMapper(IRecord metadataRecord, IRecord record) 
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.IndexLookupExecutor.ExecuteCore(IRecord inputRecord) 
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.QueryPipelineFlowExecutor.Execute(IRecord inputRecord) 
at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Processing.ExecutorProducer`1.ProcessRecord(IRecord record)
```

Comment: That would be very unusual to be the actual cause. What other updates were installed recently? What does the ULS say?

Comment: @TrevorSeward - updated the post and added ULS log

Comment: Try to SharePoint Configuration Wizard to see if it helps.